# Data Entry Transfer to Multiples Tables to Specific Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a data entry form in a sheet and I want to be able to extract the entered information and add it to the end of the table on the sheet name given in cell D-3.

The images below will give you a better picture of what I am trying to achieve.[image] and[image] I Have This VBA Code but it putt data at the end of Table (Out side)

```
Dim shCountry As Worksheet
Dim shForm As Worksheet
Dim iCurrentRow As Integer
Dim sCountryName As String

Set shForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Profit")
sCountryName = shForm.Range("D3").Value
Set shCountry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sCountryName)
iCurrentRow = shCountry.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With shCountry
         
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = shForm.Range("D5")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 2) = shForm.Range("D7")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = shForm.Range("D9")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 4) = shForm.Range("D11")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 5) = shForm.Range("D13")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 6) = shForm.Range("D15")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 7) = shForm.Range("D17")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 8) = shForm.Range("D19")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 9) = shForm.Range("D21")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 10) = shForm.Range("D23")
    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 11) = shForm.Range("D25")
     
End With

shForm.Range("D5,D7,D9,D11,D13,D15, D17, D19, D21,D23,D25").Value = ""

MsgBox "Data submitted successfully!"
```

I want my data to appear in the last row of the table before the total row۔

Comment: What do you mean by "last row of the **table**"? A real `listObject` (`Table`) or a range you name it so? Your code 'tells' to the code to place it on the first empty row. Do you want it to **insert** one row before the last one and place there the data? Is the "Total" calculated by a formula? It would be good to edit your question and place two pictures: before and after...

Comment: Sir.Total rows in the table that have SUM option within the data body range before it

Comment: Between data body range and total row (maybe i didn't understand properly)

Comment: Do you understand what a `listObject` is? If not, what about the suggested pictures to be placed in your question to better understand what you try accomplishing?

Comment: Sir FaneDuru I have updated the second picture which is coming after the data total row I want it to come before the total row

Comment: Yes I understand the list object perfectly

Comment: My data should come in the List object after the last used row, if there is no row, it should be added۔ Thanks sir for your help

Comment: I am afraid I cannot get you... When you write "AFTER" (in the picture), what did you mean? Do you want the data to be inserted outside the table, **even if you say in words that you don't**? Don't you want placing data on **a row inserted (in the table) above the 18th one (of the sheet)/5th of the table**?

Comment: Sir Matter Solved.  Just Changing This Line                                                                                                                          
 (iCurrentRow = shCountry.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) To (iCurrentRow = shCountry.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

Comment: But don't you want to insert a new row in the table and place the data in this one? Do you want **overwriting the existing row above the Total**?

Comment: Yes i want that want to insert a new row in the table and place the data in this one.  Not to overwrite.

Comment: Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It is not tested, but I think is should work as you need. I mean, it finds the necessary table, insert a row above the total and use it to drop the entry form data:

```
Sub EntryDataAboveTotalRow()
Dim shCountry As Worksheet, shForm As Worksheet, iCurrentRow As Long, sCountryName As String
Dim tbl As ListObject 'the table where to insert the row

Set shForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Profit")
sCountryName = shForm.Range("D3").value
Set shCountry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sCountryName)
Set tbl = shCountry.ListObjects(1) 'if more than a table in the sheet, use here the needed table name!

'insert a row in the table (above the Total one):
tbl.ListRows.Add (tbl.Range.rows.count - 1)
iCurrentRow = tbl.Range.rows.count - 1 'the TABLE row where to insert the data

'place the data entry values in the necessary fields:
With tbl
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 1) = shForm.Range("D5")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 2) = shForm.Range("D7")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 3) = shForm.Range("D9")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 4) = shForm.Range("D11")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 5) = shForm.Range("D13")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 6) = shForm.Range("D15")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 7) = shForm.Range("D17")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 8) = shForm.Range("D19")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 9) = shForm.Range("D21")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 10) = shForm.Range("D23")
    .Range(iCurrentRow, 11) = shForm.Range("D25")
End With

'write the formula to summarize the 6th column (new row included), if it is not kept after row insertion:
'tbl.Range(tbl.Range.rows.count, 6).Formula = "=Sum(" & _
       tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(6).Resize(tbl.DataBodyRange.rows.count - 1).address & ")"


shForm.Range("D5,D7,D9,D11,D13,D15, D17, D19, D21,D23,D25").value = ""

shCountry.Activate

MsgBox "Data submitted successfully!"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Sir FaneDuru This code is not transferring data۔

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh Did you see the comment saying "'if more than a table in the sheet, use here the needed table name!"? Did the code insert a row above the one with Total?

Comment: @Sir FaneDuru۔ Each sheet contains only one table.

Comment: This line was giving compile error **Set tbl = sh.ListObjects(1)**  Which I changed it to, **Set tbl = shCountry.ListObjects(1)** the error went away but the data didn't transfer

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh I asked about the row insertion in the respective table. Was it inserted? I am trying to understand where the problem is... If not something confidential and you have AnyDesk installed (only downloaded and open) I can remotely connect to your computer to see what's happening in your installation. I played with the code in my computer and it does what it should. Not using any entry form. Only determining the row to be inserted, inserting it and update the SUM formula.

Comment: I would like to send this file for your review, is that possible?

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh Yes, but I think that you will learn more if you can see me how debugging... And I would like to see how you use it. For me, for instance, `(iCurrentRow, 1) = shForm.Range("D5")` does not have too much meaning. I only copied from your code.

Comment: OK. I am connecting now. Please, open a Notepad window to communicate...

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh Please, delete your comment with the AD ID. Not easy to connect on it without your approval, but it is good to make it disappearing, I think...

Comment: Need a little help sorry to bother you again

Comment: The code you provided to automatically select the selected sheet was accidentally deleted by me.

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh Deletion shouldn't be a problem having the above code, I think. I only commented the part rewriting the formula in the summarized column, since your existing Subtotal formula was kept. And also activated the sheet with the table at the end. I will also write this code line. Do you feel that another remote connection will help? You should only copy the code instead of the old one...

Comment: A recheck if done

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh I already updated the code. Immediately after I wrote the above comment...

Answer (score 1):

Insert this code after the assigning of the values into the table.

```
With shCountry.listobjects(1)
    .resize .range.resize(.range.rows.count+1)
End With
```

before

```
shForm.Range("D5,D7,D9,D11,D13,D15, D17, D19, D21,D23,D25").Value = ""

MsgBox "Data submitted successfully!"
```

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh The above code adds a row **after the last one with Total**. Is this what you want? Or the row with Total is not inside the table?

Comment: If an empty row already exists, the data should be inserted into it and no need to add a new row. Enter a blank row if one does not already exist and insert data

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh How does it **already exists**? I cannot see it in the picture you show. Even if it would be there and you do not show it, would you need the code to work only once? Anyhow, the fact I cannot understand what and how you try doing it is not so important. If you are satisfied with the way of determining the necessary row you show in your comment and using the above code to add a row after the Total, is OK with me. I wish you success!

Comment: @FaneDuru  Sir you are really great and perfect person. I said this because my original file has up to 30 sheets and several tables in which I have left blank rows, that's why I said this. Shall I post another question?

Comment: This code helped me but the complete problem is still unsolvable

Comment: @Kalim Shaikh I prepared yesterday a piece of code able to insert a row and paste in it, but I was confused related to what you try doing and did not post it... I will post it now. If i will find it. I do not remember if I saved the test workbook...